# How to install drivers for AMD Radeon HD 7850?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

Could someone help me to install drivers for AMD Radeon HD 7850 graphic card?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install driver that you can download here:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

To install driver First remove old stuff by:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

then install your new driver:

```
sudo chmod 755 ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run
sudo ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run
```

***VERY IMPORTANT: if/when it gives you the number options like [1] DO NOT HIT ENTER, you must actually enter the number 1 then enter.

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

There is also a good idea to install "Catalyst Control Center" that you'll find in Package Manager