# Can I use Ubuntu for programming effectively?

Tags: programming

I am taking a course to become a programer and I am using Windows 10.

Every time I do an update of Windows it loses all my code, and breaks genymotion.

So, my question: Could I use Ubuntu for programming?

Comment: I feel like this might belong better on one of the SE sites that deals with programming, like [so], [codereview.se], or even [su].

Comment: This is a highly subjective and opinion based question.  The answer depends HIGHLY on what code base you use, what libraries you need for that code, etc., and the question is both too broad and too opinion based to be answered in its current form.

Comment: @Zacharee1 In its current form it doesn't fit anywhere :P

Comment: @ThomasW. good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

Linux and Ubuntu is more widely used by programmers, than the average - [20.5% of programmers use it](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-os) as opposed to [around 1.50% of the general population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems#Desktop_and_laptop_computers) (that doesn't include Chrome OS, and that's just desktop OS).

Note, however that both Mac OS X and Windows are used more:

[image]

Why is this? There are a number of reasons.

1. Linux has less (not none, but less) support. If my Mac goes wrong, I phone Apple. If my PC goes wrong, I phone PC World. If my Ubuntu machine dies, I'm trawling internet forums and asking here.

   Of course, this site, and the Unix & Linux one are good - but they're not professional, guaranteed support like PC World and Apple.
2. Linux has less (again, not none, but less) application support. I want to edit a video - my options are much more limited. There are often less than half the options to chose from - and a lot of those are old, unsupported and you have to compile from source.

   [image]

   Printers can be less compatible, your webcam might not work. Flash doesn't really work unless you have Google Chrome and lots of other little things are irritating.
3. I hinted at it in the last point, but Linux is a bit more... messy. You're a developer and you're used to the Terminal, but Linux needs it a lot. My terminal is always open - right now I have 3, mostly for installing my Printer drivers right now.

So what can't you code on Linux - what needs windows?

Very little to be honest. Some things are better on Windows - for example Delphi for Pascal is much better than Lazarus - and only avaliable for PC.

Almost anything can be written in Atom and then compiled with the terminal, but that doesn't mean it's easy. And there is enough windows only software that I have Windows 10 in a virtualbox.

If you're working in a team of devs using Windows, they're gonna send you Word and Excel files. Your email will likely be outlook or exchange and your calendar as well.

---

In summary, sure you can code on Ubuntu. But can you do everything else, and will it slow you down enough. 5 minutes an hour slower is 40 minutes + lost a day - that could be $25 lost easily. Add on entire days you lose because you [just-want-your-new-screens-to-connect-via-DVI-to-your-dual-head-setup-with-nVidia-and-it-just-won't-why-on-earth-not](https://askubuntu.com/a/641580/186134), and you have to ask yourself; is it worth it?

My advice, is get your Windows machine working. [The nice people at Super User may help - give them lots of details, though.](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I don't think I'd ever be able to get anything done without Linux, or with Windows.

Comment: @cat Sure, but I'm at a Windows only College, that uses Word and Powerpoint, plus sharepoint as the main interaction. I also program in Delphi which is windows only. I'm not sure what you're doing, but I find the reverse. I could use Windows exclusively (I like Windows 10 a lot) but I enjoy using Ubuntu. Also, it's free.

Comment: @Tim I am in a Linux-only work environment, and the few who had Windows on their personal computer all mainly switched to Linux (Ubuntu) since they came here, also for their all-day use. In my experience Windows is good for playing games, and basically nothing else. I do not know about OSX, since I never had one :)

Comment: @dadexix86 I use it for a number of things (personally) - I make videos and use PowerPoint for that. Word is excellect. In fact, I can't think of something I can't do on windows - i.e. I need a linux machine for.

Comment: My Linux box is heavily suited for programming and a certain amount of abuse, and my Windows box is used for Steam/gaming and a certain, but greater amount of abuse. :)

Comment: Well, Delphi starts at Eur 1000 + Eur 300/annually for mandatory subscription. Apples and oranges.